# Is there any global control to set the defaults for Empties in 2.8?

Tags: scripting, rigging

Is there any global control to set the defaults (type, size etc) for Empties in 2.8?

In this instance, I am creating a spline controller and using Ctrl+H to hook and create control objects. An empty is created automatically, but the default is a tiny cross. So later I have to go to each one separately and change the type and size. Is there a default setting I can edit, or does anyone know a script that will do it to multiple empties at once?